# Start new threads in each loop and control amount of threads to be not more than x-amount at the same time

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I have been writing "linear" winforms for couple of months and now I am trying to figure out threading.

this is my loop that has around 40,000 rows and it takes around 1 second to perform a task on this row:

```
foreach (String CASE in MAIN_CASES_LIST)
{
//bunch of code here
}
```

How do I

1. put each loop into separate thread
2. maintain no more than x-amount of threads at the same time

Comment: What exactly is "bunch of code" here doing?  Threading might actually make this *slower.*

Comment: Why on earth would you want anywhere *near* 100 threads? If you have many more threads than cores/processors, you will end up spending way too much time context switching, and not enough time performing useful work. You should take a look at the task parallel library (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx). It abstracts the details of threading away from you nicely.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limit Threads count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334178/limit-threads-count)

Comment: Be sure to note that winforms will be quite unhappy if you try modifying a UI component from one of your worker threads. This includes databinding scenarios where modifying a datasource raises events to a UI control.

Comment: Have you considered Parallel.For loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on .NET 4 you can utilize [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992001.aspx)

```
Parallel.ForEach(MAIN_CASES_LIST, CASE => 
{ 

    //bunch of code here 

});
```

Comment: how about doung this for this type of loop: 'foreach (DataRow item in listOfItems.Rows)' ?

Comment: @Cory packet loss occurred between my mind and my fingers.  edited to include '4'.

Comment: works for strings, but give me an error when I try to loop dataRow `Parallel.ForEach(listOfItems.Rows, item =>` Error: `Error 1 The type arguments for method 'System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach<TSource>(System.Collections.Concurrent.OrderablePartitioner<TSource>, System.Action<TSource,System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelLoopState,long>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

Comment: @Andrew: Then try `Parallel.ForEach(listOfItems.AsEnumerable(), item => { // do stuff });`

Comment: @Cory do you know how to approach the Paallel to `XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/s:smap/s:sitemap", magr);` ? I need to loop over all `xnList` elements

Comment: @Andrew: You could convert your `xnList` to an array of `XmlNode`s and use that as the first argument: `Parallel.ForEach(xnList.Cast<XmlNode>().ToArray(), ...);` (or you to do `.ToList()` instead of `.ToArray()`).

Comment: I ended up counting the elements and did the `Parallel.For` loop

Answer (score 1):

There's a great library called SmartThreadPool which may be useful here, it does a lot of useful stuff with threading and queueing, abstracting most of this away from you

Not sure if it will help you, but you can queue up a crapload of work items, limit the number of threads, etc etc

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7933/Smart-Thread-Pool

Of course if you want to get your hands dirty with multi-threading or use Parallel go for it, it's just a suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

To mix the answers above, and add a limit to the maximum number of threads created, you can use this overloaded call.  Just be sure to add "using System.Threading.Tasks;" at the top.

```
LinkedList<String> theList = new LinkedList<string>();

ParallelOptions parOptions = new ParallelOptions();

parOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5; //only up to 5 threads allowed.

Parallel.ForEach(theList.AsEnumerable(), parOptions , (string CASE) => 
{ 

    //bunch of code here 

});
```